# Select Directory ASP.NET MVC-5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5

Part of my requirements say a user needs to be able to export an HTML table (populated via the controller) to excel. I can do create a .csv and export it. However I need to be able to let them select a directory.

***HTML5 Answer***:

```
   <input type="file">
```

However this does not let you select a directory, only a specific file.

***JavaScript***:

Everywhere I read, this is a big security threat. Although there are some hacks I really don't want to use that.

I tried to make a call to FolderBrowserDialog from the controller when you hit the function but I am missing assemblies reference and cannot find the correct one.

***My Question***: if you had to let a user select a directoy, where a file will be exported to, in an ASP.NET MVC5 project how would you do it? HTML5, JavaScript/JQuery, C# doesn't matter to me. No security threats!

Thanks guys

Comment: Sounds like you are duplicating work already provided by the browser. After you created the `CSV` put it on the server ready for download (either a dedicated folder which gets cleaned out or a separate document management server) and send a download link to the file back to the client. The user then either clicks a link to the file or an iframe with the URL set to the file can trigger it which opens the browsers default `SaveAs` dialog letting the user choose where to download the file to.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl so should the view make an aJax call to do that? can you provide an article, or some code on how to do this?

Comment: We use MVC3 and don't use the HTML5 file input. So the ajax request returns the URL to the file we created. The script then set the iframe URL to that location and the dialog is triggered. I;m not saying this is normal :) it's just how we ended up doing it. Not sure if MVC5 can do it easier/better. Eitherway the browser's default `SaveAs` should be used in the end for saving the file.

Comment: MVC5 is beautiful compared to MVC3 and MVC4 haha I will try it and update if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the 'Content-Disposition' header to 'attachment' when you are generating the file. This will cause the normal browser save dialog to pop up and they can navigate and save it wherever they want.

So in your ActionMethod, I'm assuming you are doing something like:
... create the csv ...
return File(csvData, "text/csv");

That method has an overload that accepts a default filename. If you set the filename, it will automatically add the content-disposition header for you and cause the file to be downloaded instead of opened.

return File(csvData, "text/csv", "somefile.csv");

Comment: I'm actually not returning a file. If I do return a file, will it download on the users browser?

Comment: Depends, that's what the `Content-Disposition` header determines. If it's set to "attachment" as indicated here, yes, it will prompt a download. Otherwise, the browser will default to trying to display it in the browser if it's a displayable format. (I'm actually not sure with CSV. It's plain text, but the browser may prompt a download regardless).

Answer (score 0):

First, when you say "select a directory to export a file to", are you talking client-side or server-side? If it's being pushed to the user as a download, you have no control over anything: where it's stored or what it's even named.

If you're talking server-side, then you can handle it one of two ways. You can either just populate a select list with directory choices, and then use that to build a path on submit. Or you could take the more complicated route of trying to create an interface to browse the server's filesystem. There's nothing builtin to help you here; you'll have to create it yourself or find some third-party tool to do it for you. Basically, you just use the I/O tools to read a list of directories, and present that to the user in a tree style hierarchy.

Comment: No I create a file server side (in the controller) and set the path the client's machine. I'm surprised it worked as well but I have no issues.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but it is absolutely impossible to directly write to a client's machine. If this is an internal network, you might somehow be able to get the client's host and write through the network, but that's not only a little scary (as it would require you app having some insane network privileges) but also not really the same thing as writing to the client: you're just writing to a connected network resource that happens to be the client's machine.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will definitely look at this. I was unaware of this issue. I really like @Malevolence answer of returning a file. But the question is how would that look in the view? as a download? any security issues here?

Comment: With a download? No, there's no security issues, other than the usual for any resource: available only to those who are allow to access it, especially with sensitive information. In that scenario, you wouldn't have a view, you're just returning the file itself as a response instead of an HTML document.